# Twenty Eleven theme header images manual next previous buttons

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven, header-image

I have 3 images in my twenty eleven theme header and they rotate by themseleves I want to add next and forward buttons on left and right of my header image to also rotate them manually when I want to see next header image. please guide

Answer (score 1):

the header image in the Twenty Twelve theme is a random image on page load.

As it is random ... it's difficult to put next and forward links 
  - how can you tell if you started with image 1, 3 or x -

In addition, the header is most likely loaded as a background image so you'd have to do some harder coding to avoid a page reload to change from image 1 to image x

If what you are trying to achieve is to have a slider / featured post panel on the homepage then there are many plugins for this.

Comment: thanks for replying. i got what i needed by nivo slider.